# How to automate build (.NET Services)

Tags: powershell, msbuild, build-automation

I am trying to automate build process (not Continuous Integration):

1. Get the code from TFS.
2. Compile and create build package.
3. Push the code to a desired shared location.

Should I consider using PowerShell or will `msbuild` through Command Prompt suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work.  We use TFS build definitions to execute MSBuild and MSDeploy.exe commands for our deployments.  You can build via the commandline with:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

Then use MSDeploy to package the deployment and deploy:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:dirPath="C:\source\myProject\bin\Release" -dest:package=c:\package.zip
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=C:\package.zip -dest:iisApp="Site1/App1" -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```